# DataGrid for Primefaces, This doesn't change the Color

Tags: css, primefaces, datagrid

I want that the color of DataGrid is transparent because I want see background image.

I am using primefaces 6.

css:

```
.ui-datagrid .ui-paginator {
    background-color: transparent;
}
.ui-datagrid .ui-datagrid-content .ui-datagrid-colum .ui-widget-content .ui-grid ui-grid-responsive{
    background-color: transparent;
}

.ui-grid-row{
    background-color: transparent;
}

.ui-datagrid .ui-{
    background-color: transparent;
}
.ui-panel {
    background-color: transparent;
}
.ui-facet{
    background-color: transparent;
}
.ui-panelgrid{
    background-color: transparent;
}
```

Thanks You!

Comment: so you are saying this does not make it transparent... Then you can use the browser developer tool to see what css IS applied to not make it transparent

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use: `background:none;` to make sure both `background-image` and `background-color` are none.

Comment: This most likely is true (99% sure). But also better to point the poster to how to resolve these things...  (learning to fish instead of giving fish)

Comment: The problem is that Primefaces doesn't get style, because I have write ." ui - datagrid" in file css, but this doesn't get.

Comment: You need to match the elements class name with what you have in your CSS file. Is this possible for you to provide a jsfiddle or a live sample, so we can check?

Comment: or providing a screenshot from your firebug HTML tab, showing the generated HTML element for datagrid; it's appreciated.

Comment: resolved, I had to follow the hierarchy of dataGrid to modify the internal elements

Comment: .ui-datagrid .ui-datagrid-content{
     background-color: transparent;
}

.ui-datagrid .ui-widget-content{
     background-color: transparent;
}

.ui-datagrid .ui-grid{
     background-color: transparent;
}

.ui-datagrid ui-grid-responsive{
     background-color: transparent;
}


.ui-datagrid .ui-grid-row{
    background-color: transparent;
}